# Importing a single greek letter from another font

Tags: fonts

I know versions of this question [have](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509836/change-font-of-single-greek-letter-in-math-environment-for-all-equations-classi) already [been](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) asked, but I've already spent a couple of hours trying to make their answers work in my case, and wasn't able to.

I would like a dedicated symbol to use for Kronecker deltas, which doesn't get confused with other deltas in my document. For this I would like to import the delta from one of the fonts in [this](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) list, say the one on page 9. I only want to import one character, and would like a new command for it that does not overwrite the ordinary `\delta`. What is the quickest way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Antykwa Toruńska font (you can see to pag. 30, https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/antt/doc/fonts/antt/AntykwaTorunska-doc-en-2_03.pdf - https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/anttvf) have the symbol `\delta` the nr. 228: `\symbol{228}`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I still don't see how to load that character individually (if I `\usepackage{anttor}` the font for the whole document changes).

Comment: Are you sure your readers will notice the difference?

Comment: @egreg probably not, but I might draw their attention to it. There are other (non-Kronecker) deltas in the same equations, so I think it's nice to have a different symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will be different depending on whether you use `unicode-math` or legacy 7-bit math fonts.  Here is a solution that uses `unicode-math` if the engine supports it, and otherwise falls back to the font you specified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} % For /iftutex
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % To format this MWE for TeX.SX
\pagestyle{empty}

\iftutex
  % LuaTeX or XeTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfontface\altgrfont{AntykwaTorunskaMed-Italic.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
  \newcommand{\kronecker}{\altgrfont{δ}}
\else
  % PDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{altgr}{OML}{antt}{m}{it}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\kronecker}{\mathord}{altgr}{"0E}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  Kronecker delta & \texttt{{\textbackslash}delta} & \texttt{{\textbackslash}partial} \\
  \(\kronecker\)  & \(\delta\)                 & \(\partial\)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: antt font sample]

In PDFTeX, you can change the family name to get another font, or even change `OML` to `LGR` to use a LGR-encoded font.  if you don’t want to waste one of your limited number of math alphabets on this one symbol, you could instead switch to `\textnormal` and generate it with text-mode commands, e.g. `\usefont` followed by `\symbol`.

You would need one extra line of code in each case to declare a `bold` version, which you might for example use in a bold header.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.

Comment: Great....answer.

Comment: Not sure why you suggest Artemisia, when Antikwa Toruńska is also available as an OpenType font in TeX Live: `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/antt/`

Comment: @egreg I’d used it before in other answers, because a question years ago requested it. But, producing the same output on all engines would probably have been better here.